# Unable to enter into the folder Ubuntu Permission denied error

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am new to docker,

I just created a volume, when I inspect **docker volume inspect web-volume**,
it show MountPoint : **"var/lib/docker/volumes/web-**volume/_data"

When I cd into  var/lib/docker/volumes/web-volume/_data, I am getting Permission denied error.

How to go to that folder?

I tried entering to the folder but unable to enter.

I am expecting, how to change the permission to that folder, so that I can enter.

Comment: You can't usually edit the files in a volume or container directly from the host.  If you need to run your program against files that live on the host, Docker's filesystem isolation features might not meet your needs, and a non-container process might be easier to run.  Also consider a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) instead of a named volume.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is how to change permissions. You can change permissions using the [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) command.